# SQS messages are always one message behind in serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I am working with a serverless API, and I have a lambda function triggered from an sqs queue, with the batch size of 1, which means my intention is to trigger the lambda soon as I send a message to the queue, it's working fine but when I deploy the function for the first time it's not triggering and and when i request for the second time it is sending the first message, it is always one message behind what I am sending. I have attached my code, not sure what I am missing here, any help is appreciated.

serverless.yml

```
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
      - "sqs:SendMessage"
      - "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
    Resource: "arn:aws:sqs:${self:provider.region}:*:EmailQueueDev"

functions:
   sendGrid:
      handler: handler.sendGrid
      events:
        - sqs: 
            arn: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:${file(./config.js):sqs.account_id}:EmailQueueDev
            batchSize: 1
resources:
 Resources:
   EmailQueue:
     Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
     Properties:
       QueueName: "EmailQueueDev"
```

code

```
module.exports.sendEmail = async (event) => {

  // Trigger the SQS for SendGrid Function To Execute
  const sqs = new aws.SQS();
  const params = {
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(transaction.data),
    QueueUrl: process.env.QUE_URL
  }

  sqs.sendMessage(params, (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      log(JSON.stringify({info: 'Errors sending message to the Queue', trace: err}));
    }
    else console.log('data is', data);
  });

};
```

Comment: Can you check if there is any message in-flight for that queue?

Comment: no @qkhanhpro, it shows 0

Comment: 0 in-flight and 0 for message in queue count also? That is very strange indeed

Comment: Yes, I am receiving all the messages but not immediately

Comment: The only other thing I can think of which can effect the delivery rate of your queue is that there are some "Delivery Delay" introduced for your SQS. But I dont think it is enabled by default
It would be best if you can capture the console screen for your SQS + Lambda current configuration

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just pull all the available messages when your Lambda is triggered?

Comment: @stdunbar nope, no such requirements

Comment: Your sendEmail function is not ideal and may be causing the problem by exiting too early. See the async/await example at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/ for how to use the .promise() variants of the AWS methods.

Answer (score 1):

the "batchSize" parameter indicates the maximum number of messages to process per function invocation and doesn't affect when the lambda function is triggered. When you define SQS as your event source, AWS created 5 parallel long-polling connections and when it receives something in the queue, it triggers your function. How long do you wait after sending the first message to see if it triggers the function or not? there might be a small delay between the message receiving in the queue and the function being triggered.